# Magento 2 cms backend javascript error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, magento2

Suddenly I am having javascript error and cannot edit any cms page (cms/page/edit/page_id/45) or block. I have been trying to solve this for the past week with no success. I have also tried removing the modules that I have installed recently.

I did not touch any core files and I have updated file permissions but still get this error below in chrome console from the core static files

```
VM6148:68 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at template (template.js:79:36)
at render (template.js:140:24)
at iterate (template.js:236:33)
at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js:150:9)
at Object.template (template.js:206:15)
at UiClass.initConfig (class.js:89:28)
at UiClass._super (wrapper.js:106:35)
at UiClass.initConfig (abstract.js:123:18)
at UiClass.initConfig (wrapper.js:109:34)
at UiClass._super (wrapper.js:106:35)
```

[Image showing spinner and javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DJh5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a database issue due to js injection. Patching a 3rd party extension fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: may I know how is it patched? I will explore this path

Comment: In my case, it was a vulnerability in Mirasvit_Sorting. Updating the extension will fix the issue and patch the bug.

Comment: @TLWX, thanks! You saved me. I have had this extension way before I experience this issue, thus I didn't expect it will be this. Updating solved the issue for me.